# How to change current date-time format in the footer of a pdf document using PuppeteerSharp

Tags: puppeteer, .net-5, puppeteer-sharp

I have a .Net 5 application that uses PuppeteerSharp(5.1.0) to convert Html files to pdf documents. I need to show the current date-time in the footer of the pdf document. I am using the following code to show the footer content.

Footer template:

```
var footerTemplate = @"<div style=""display: flex; justify-content: space-between; font-size: 8px; margin: 0px 45px 0px 45px; width: 100%"">
                                        <div class=""date""></div>
                                        <div>Page <span class=""pageNumber""></span><span> of </span><span class=""totalPages""></span></div>
                                   </div>";
```

PuppeteerSharp pdf generation code:

```
var marginOptions = new MarginOptions()
{
    Left = "60px",
    Right = "60px",
    Bottom = "80px",
    Top = "60px"
};
await puppeteer.PDF(htmlFilePath, outputPath, new PuppeteerSharp.PdfOptions
         {
             Format = PuppeteerSharp.Media.PaperFormat.A4,
             PrintBackground = true,
             Landscape = true,
             MarginOptions = marginOptions,
             DisplayHeaderFooter = true,
             HeaderTemplate = "<div></div>",
             FooterTemplate = footerTemplate"
          });
```

It shows the current date-time like this:
[faulty date-time footer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNFka.jpg)

But I need to show the current date-time like that.
[correct date-time footer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HF24H.png)

How can I format the date-time in the footer?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `<div class=""date""></div>`, you can insert the date value into the div yourself and not use the `date` class.

For example:

```cs
var spanDate = $"<span>{DateTime.Now:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss}</span>";
var pdfContent = await page.PdfStreamAsync(new PdfOptions
{
    Format = PaperFormat.A4,
    PrintBackground = true,
    DisplayHeaderFooter = true,
    HeaderTemplate = @$"
        <div style=""width: 100%; font-size: 11px; padding: 15px 15px 0; color: #bbb; position: relative;"">
            <div style=""position: absolute; left: 20px; top: 5px;"">{spanDate}</div>
        </div>",
    FooterTemplate = @$"
        <div style=""width: 100%; font-size: 9px; padding: 15px 15px 0; color: #bbb; position: relative;"">
            <div style=""position: absolute; left: 20px; top: 5px;"">
                <span>Generated at </span>{spanDate}
            </div>
            <div style=""position: absolute; right: 20px; top: 5px;"">
                <span class=""pageNumber""></span>/<span class=""totalPages""></span>
            </div>
        </div>",
    MarginOptions = new MarginOptions { Left = "2cm", Right = "2cm", Bottom = "1cm", Top = "2cm" }
});
```